# Move draggable to position programmatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

Lets say there is a draggable object capable of being dragged only on one axis.

Is there a way to programmatically move it? Either to start, or by a delta. Of course I could go and change its css `left` property, but that wouldn't trigger the dragging events jQuery offers.

I was expecting to find a `dragBy(x,y)` method to the draggable.

Here is the example: http://jsfiddle.net/odyodyodys/daHU8/

html:

```
<div id="theButton">Reset position</div>
<div id="theDiv">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
```

Js:

```
$("#theDiv").draggable({
    axis: "x",
    cursor: "pointer"
});
```

Css:

```
#theDiv {
    display:block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-top: 80px;
    background-color: green;
}
#theButton {
    border: 1px solid;
    width:80px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Is there a way to move the draggable element (the `theDiv` here) by a delta or to the initial position, after moving it across the x axis?

Comment: am i missing something in the fiddle?

Comment: I cannot save it for some reason. Edited the question to include jsfiddle code. Sorry about that.

Comment: Fiddle is ok now. Sorry guys

Comment: no problem, i thought i was going crazy

Comment: Here you go dude, i think this is what you want... http://jsfiddle.net/vwZMZ/2/

Comment: why don't you set this as an answer? it's exactly what I was looking for Thank you

Comment: There you go, as requested

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/vwZMZ/2/)

Using extra javascript sources you can achieve what you are looking for.

From jQuery UI:
[jquery.simulate.js](http://j-ulrich.github.com/jquery-simulate-ext/jquery.simulate.js)

From 3rd party:
Source: http://j-ulrich.github.io/jquery-simulate-ext/
[jquery.simulate.ext.js](http://j-ulrich.github.com/jquery-simulate-ext/jquery.simulate.ext.js)
[jquery.simulate.drag-n-drop.js](http://j-ulrich.github.com/jquery-simulate-ext/jquery.simulate.drag-n-drop.js)

Props to j-ulrich for making it so easy.

```
function dragTo(x, y) {
    $("#draggable").simulate("drag-n-drop", {dx: x, dy: y, interpolation: { stepWidth: 1, stepDelay: 1}});
}
```