# Why ActionChains does not work in PhantomJS Webdriver but works in Chrome Webdriver?

Tags: python-2.7, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, phantomjs, selenium-chromedriver

I would like to change a slider handle using PhantomJS but it does not work. Please check the following codes that work under Chrome Webdriver but not in PhantomJS. These codes try to slide the handle with the amount of 10% of slider bar's width to the right.
Any idea to make it work for PhantomJS?

```
from browsermobproxy import Server
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains

# settings for choosing Chrome or PhantomJS:
#...
#...
#driver = webdriver.Chrome(...) or webdriver.PhantomJS(...)

url = "http://jqueryui.com/slider/"
driver.get(url)
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.TAG_NAME, "iframe")))

handle_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#slider > span")))
bar_element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#slider")
offset = bar_element.size['width'] * 0.1

print "Initial handle location:", handle_element.get_attribute("style")

move = ActionChains(driver)
move.click_and_hold(handle_element).move_by_offset(offset, 0).release().perform()

print "Handle location after sliding:", handle_element.get_attribute("style")

print "Slider bar size:", bar_element.size['width']
```

Output when driver is Chrome:

```
Initial handle location: left: 0%;
Handle location after sliding: left: 10%;
Slider bar size: 548
```

Output when driver is PhantomJS:

```
Initial handle location: left: 0%;
Handle location after sliding: left: 0%;
Slider bar size: 444
```

Comment: @ArtjomB. thank you for your comment. I am a beginner. So, could you please let me know what "synthetic events" are?

Comment: Sorry, didn't receive your notification, because I deleted my comment and made it into an answer. If you have jQuery on the page, you can try something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21588122/move-draggable-to-position-programmatically) through `driver.execute_script()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PhantomJS doesn't support dragging natively. You will have to try with synthetic events.

> For 'mousemove', however, there is no button pressed (i.e. it is not dragging)

[Source](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/send-event.html)

If you have jQuery on the page, you can try something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21588122/move-draggable-to-position-programmatically) through `driver.execute_script()`. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19384710/javascript-workaround-for-drag-and-drop-in-selenium-webdriver/26372276#26372276) is an example with ruby.

Comment: And JS native: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596481/is-it-possible-to-simulate-key-press-events-programmatically

Comment: @User That's exactly what I mean by "synthetic events".

Comment: You also provided a link to ruby while the question is tagged python